# how can i achive this UI on my custom table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uibezierpath

i want to achive this custom shape on my tableviewcell how could i do it?

[UITableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJNiF.png)

Comment: Please, provide some code showing us what you already tried.

Comment: i just tried a simple round rect uibezierpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIBezierPath` with arc.

Add this class to your view.

```
class CellShapeView: UIView {
    
    var fillColor: UIColor = .yellow
    
    private var path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        //For Round corners
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).addClip()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height))
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height))
        
        //Right Side circle arc
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                    radius: 10,
                    startAngle: CGFloat((270 * Double.pi) / 180),
                    endAngle: CGFloat((90 * Double.pi) / 180),
                    clockwise: false)
        
        
        path.close()
        fillColor.setFill()
        path.fill()
        
    }
}
```

[image]